# Multiple spinners using one list with different values

Tags: java, android, arraylist, spinner

I have the following code, which adds spinners based on a loop (my loop is different in my real version, but simplified here since the outcome is the same).

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++{
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
spinner.setId(result.getInt(0));

Cursor result2 = databaseHelper.retrieveData(DatabaseHelper.LISTTABLE,"`Select list`",result.getString(8),null);
listDynamic.clear();
listDynamic.add("");
for(int j = 0; j < result2.getCount(); j++){
result2.moveToNext();
listDynamic.add(result2.getString(7));
}

ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listDynamic);
spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
result2.close();


listSpinners.add(spinner);
rlParent.addView(spinner);
}
```

So what works: The spinners work as expected.

The code produces this result: The spinners will only use the last iteration of listDynamic and arrayAdapter. Basically resulting in the following:

Spinner 1

1. Q
2. W
3. E

Spinner 2

1. Q
2. W
3. E

The result that should happen (in my mind) is that there should be two different lists shown in each spinner. Similar to this:

Spinner 1

1. A
2. B
3. C

Spinner 2

1. Q
2. W
3. E

I suspect there is a thing about ArrayAdapters that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using same list for both spinners that why items are same .

**Solution 1**: declare listDynamic locally  .
listDynamic.clear();   -> List listDynamic=new Arraylist();

**Solution 2**: use different list object for different spinners listDynamic1,listDynamic2 ...